# Prawn PDF - How to get the height of a text box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

I have a formatted_text_box that contains dynamic text.  It seems like the box just expands nicely when not given specific dimensions.

The problem is it doesn't seem to move the cursor to the bottom of the box so my text overlaps with the text in the formatted_text_box.

If I could determine the height of the text box I could use move_down accordingly.

Is there any way to determine the height of a text_box on the page?

Answer (score 9):

Expanding on Abraham's stubbed answer:

1. create the formatted text box, making sure to pass in options you normally pass to the helper method `pdf.formatted_text_box`

   ```
   features_box = ::Prawn::Text::Formatted::Box.new(feature_text.flatten, {
       at: [@pdf.bounds.left + 3.in, @pdf.bounds.top - 0.7.in],
       inline_format: true,
       document: @pdf
     }
   )
   ```
2. dry_run the box `features_box.render(dry_run: true)`
3. grab the box height `@height = features_box.height`
4. render the box for real `features_box.render`
5. move the cursor or start another box at the new height

Comment: Relevant documentation link: http://prawnpdf.org/docs/0.11.1/Prawn/Text/Formatted/Box.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the :dry_run=> true option?

http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/docs/0.11.1/Prawn/Text/Box.html

There is a similar case here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/prawn-ruby/fjPBlaqtQ3A/iGKNThxbq0oJ

Comment: This answer isn't very helpful. Can you please explain further.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution which renders a numbered list.  Each row consists of an array of number, text, e.g. ["1.", "list item 1", "2.", "list item 2"]

```ruby
h = data.collect{|d| pdf.height_of(d[0])}.max
data.each do |row|
  pdf.formatted_text(format_line(row[0]))
  pdf.formatted_text_box(format_line(row[1]), :at=>[w, pdf.cursor+h])
  pdf.move_down pdf.height_of_formatted(format_line(row[1]))-h
end
pdf.move_down pdf.height_of_formatted(format_line(data.last[1]))
```

Move down the height of the formatted text to render the next row.